# ORMLITE Join 3 Tables with 2 search parameters

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, ormlite

I am looking for a solution for a ORMLite Issue with 3 joined tables and 2 like parameters.

There are 5 tables in the database (3 main tables and 2 dependency tables). The database is build as follows:

Alarms >> AlarmEvent << Event >> EventCalendar << Calendars

Now I try to get all Events which are included in one special Alarm and which are refering on one calendar. But when I run my query I see allways all events, and I have no idea how to solve this.
Here is my latest function for this query.

```
    private PreparedQuery<EventItem> makeEventsForCalendarAndAlarmQuery(
        int Alarmid, int CalId) throws SQLException {

    QueryBuilder<AlarmEntry, Integer> alarmQb = getHelper()
            .getAlarmListDao().queryBuilder();
    QueryBuilder<AlarmEvent, Integer> alarmEventQb = getHelper()
            .getAlarmEventDao().queryBuilder();
    QueryBuilder<EventItem, Integer> eventQb = getHelper()
            .getEventItemDao().queryBuilder();
    QueryBuilder<CalendarEvent, Integer> calendarEventQb = getHelper()
            .getCalendarEventDao().queryBuilder();
    QueryBuilder<CalendarDb, Integer> calendarDbQb = getHelper()
            .getCalendarDbDao().queryBuilder();

    alarmEventQb.leftJoin(alarmQb);
    eventQb.leftJoin(alarmEventQb);
    calendarEventQb.leftJoin(eventQb);
    calendarDbQb.where().like(CalendarDb.CAL_ID_FIELD_NAME, CalId);
    calendarDbQb.join(calendarEventQb);
    eventQb.join(calendarDbQb);
    return eventQb.prepare();
}
```

How do I have to setup the query to get only Events which are refering to one selected Alarm and one selected Calendar?

EDIT:
The SQL statement should look anything like this. I am a beginner in sql so it is possible that the statement is not correct:

```
SELECT * FROM EventItem INNER JOIN (CalendarEvent INNER JOIN  CalendarDb WHERE id = calid) INNER JOIN (AlarmEvent INNER JOIN AlarmEntry where AlarmEntry.id = alarmId)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok the issue seems to be solved.
I setup the following code:

```
    calendarEventQb.where().eq(CalendarEvent.CALENDARDB_ID_FIELD_NAME, CalId);
    alarmEventQb.where().eq(AlarmEvent.ALARMENTRY_ID_FIELD_NAME, Alarmid);

    eventQb.join(calendarEventQb).join(alarmEventQb);
```

With this statement I get the data I was looking for.